# What "Contraint is no smaller than the instance head" means and how to solve it

Tags: haskell

I would like to write something like:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts,FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString,pack)
import Data.Foldable (Foldable)

class (Show a) => Rows a where
    rRepr :: a -> [ByteString]
    rRepr = (:[]) . pack . show

instance (Foldable f,Show (f a)) => Rows (f a) where
    rRepr = const []
```

meaning that `f a` instantiate `Rows` if `f` instantiate `Foldable` and `f a` instantiate `Show`. When I run ghc I get:

```
Constraint is no smaller than the instance head
  in the constraint: Show (f a)
(Use -XUndecidableInstances to permit this)
In the instance declaration for `Rows (f a)'
```

I have two questions:

- what "smaller" means in the error and what is the problem?
- what is the right way to define what I want without using `UndecidableInstances`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell Constraint is no smaller than the instance head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198907/haskell-constraint-is-no-smaller-than-the-instance-head)

Comment: In future, as a convenience to anyone who tries to answer a question, you might want to include the imports and tell us which line the error message pointed to. In this case, I added `import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString, pack)` and
`import Data.Foldable (Foldable)`. The error is on the `instance ...` line.

Comment: @jberryman I read that post but I couldn't understand how to adapt the answers to my case.

@mhwombat added the imports. I didn't put the line number because the ghc error output is clear about that. The error is on the  constraint `Show (f a)` of the instance declaration `Rows (f a)`

Comment: Isn't `Show (f a)` already implied by the class constraint?

Comment: @Ingo no, the class constraint `Show a` says that to be a `Rows`, the type `a` must instantiate `Show`. It is not automatic.

Comment: @jberryman, seems like same error message but not same question...

Comment: @HaskellElephant I think all the answers to this question are in the answers and comments to the other question. But it doesn't hurt having more explanation of a tricky concept

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's play compiler: we have a type `(f a)` we'd like to see if it is a valid satisfier of a `Rows` constraint. To do so, we need to dispatch a proof that `(f a)` satisfies `Show (f a)` as well. This isn't a problem unless someone writes an

```
 instance Rows (f a) => Show (f a) where ...
```

in which case I'm back where I began. Encoding an infinite loop like this is sort of foolish, but Haskell statically ensures that it's actually impossible unless you ask for `UndecidableInstances`.

---

Normally Haskell ensures that each step of a "resolution chase" reduces the size of the type by at least 1 constructor. This leads to a really simple proof by structural induction that we'll end up with a bare type in a finite number of resolutions.

This is overly restrictive, clearly some instance resolution steps are meaningful, useful, and total even if they don't immediately reduce the constructor tree. This same kind of totality restriction applies in languages like Agda and Coq and often it's a bit of an illustrative challenge to manipulate your algorithm into one which proceeds by structural induction.

---

So how can we fix it? One way is to lose the `Show` constraint on the `class` definition use an instance like `Show1` from [prelude-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/prelude-extras/0.3/doc/html/Prelude-Extras.html).

```
class Show1 f where ...
show1 :: (Show1 f, Show a) => f a -> String  -- not an instance definition!
```

and then have `instance (Foldable f, Show1 f, Show a) => Rows (f a) where ...` which works in my testing. You can then write a default instance as a standalone function.

```
defRRepr :: Show a => a -> [ByteString]
defRRepr = (:[]) . pack . show
```

and use it whenever writing an instance definition for a `Show`able thing.

---

The other solution is to use `newtype` wrappers to allow Haskell to see that a "layer" of resolution has been removed.

```
instance (Foldable f, Show (f a)) => Rows (FoldableRow f a) where
    rRepr = const [] . unFR

newtype FoldableRow f a = FR { unFR :: f a } deriving (Show)
```

Comment: Nice answer, made me introduce a newtype rather than going with `UndecidableInstances` (though that would have worked as well). The newtype communicates intent more explicitly.