# Why can't the Show instance be derived for MaybeT?

Tags: haskell

If I define the monad transformer type for `Identity`, it is able to derive the `Show` instance.

```
newtype IdentityT f a =
  IdentityT { runIdentityT :: f a }
  deriving (Show)
```

will derive

```
instance Show (f a) => Show (IdentityT f a)
```

But if I define the monad transformer type for `Maybe`

```
newtype MaybeT m a =
  MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
  deriving (Show)
```

I get the error

```
• No instance for (Show (m (Maybe a)))
        arising from the first field of ‘MaybeT’ (type ‘m (Maybe a)’)
```

Since `Maybe a` has a `Show` instance, I would expect it to work and derive

```
instance Show (m (Maybe a)) => Show (MaybeT m a)
```

Why can't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC uses a heuristics to determine if an instance guarantees search termination.
By termination here, we mean that, when searching for an instance we will not loop forever. Concretely,this must be forbidden

```
instance Show a => Show a where ...
```

as well as this

```
instance Show [a] => Show a where ...
```

GHC roughly requires that constraints in the instance context (the part before the `=>`) must be "smaller" than the constraint in the head (after the `=>`). So, it accepts this:

```
instance Show a => Show [a] where ...
```

since `a` contains one type constructor less than `[a]`.

It also accepts this:

```
instance Show (f a) => Show (IdentityT f a) where ...
```

since `f a` contains one type constructor less than `IdentityT f a`.

However,

```
instance Show (f (Maybe a)) => Show (MaybeT f a) where ...
```

uses the same number of constructors! Hence, it is not accepted to be sure it will not cause a loop. After all, later on, we might meet

```
instance Show (MaybeT f a)) => Show (f (Maybe a)) where ...
```

and it's clear that at least one of these two instances must be rejected to guarantee termination. GHC chooses to reject both of them.

`UndecidableInstances` relaxes this restriction. GHC will accept both instances, and now the burden is on us to avoid loops.

Comment: This is great hard to find anwer... Helped me with my today's problem well after 2 hours of nonsense. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think we can see the issue by following GHC's suggestions (I'm using 8.2.1) until we hit a dead end:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| newtype MaybeT m a =
Prelude|   MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
Prelude|   deriving (Show)
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:12:13: error:
    • No instance for (Show (m (Maybe a)))
        arising from the first field of ‘MaybeT’ (type ‘m (Maybe a)’)
      Possible fix:
        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
          so you can specify the instance context yourself
    • When deriving the instance for (Show (MaybeT m a))
Prelude> :set -XStandaloneDeriving 
Prelude> deriving instance Show (m (Maybe a)) =>  Show (MaybeT m a)

<interactive>:17:19: error:
    • The constraint ‘Show (m (Maybe a))’
        is no smaller than the instance head
      (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
    • In the stand-alone deriving instance for
        ‘Show (m (Maybe a)) => Show (MaybeT m a)’
```

Okay, so `Show` wasn't derivable for `MaybeT` likely because that constraint would have been disallowed, as it's the sort of constraint the typechecker can't prove termination about. You can read more about what "no smaller than instance head" means in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17866970/176841

Comment: But its second suggestion, to enable `UndecidableInstances`, is perfectly fine.

Comment: So I can use `UndecidableInstances` to get the compiler to derive the instance for me, but what about the `MaybeT` type makes it unable to derive without that while it can handle the `IdentityT` type just fine? Ex. I would expect it to be able to show `MaybeT [Just 1]` without any extensions