# How to make a type class instance of another type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm making a `Boolean` data, that accepts others types as boolean values, just for fun. I have created the data `Boolean`, for representing the actual `Boolean` value, and I have made a class named `Booleanizable`, that represents values that can be turned into Boolean data. The problem is the following: I want to make a single `instance` statement for every type that belongs to `Num` class, instead of making a statement for each type. How do I do that?
Just to make it clearer, the code:

```
module Boolean(
    Boolean,
    true,
    false,
    Booleanizable
) where



data Boolean = Boolean Int

false = Boolean 0
true = Boolean 1

instance Show Boolean where
    show (Boolean 0) = "false"
    show (Boolean 1) = "true"

instance Eq Boolean where
    (Boolean 0) == (Boolean 0) = True
    (Boolean 0) == (Boolean 1) = False
    (Boolean 1) == (Boolean 1) = True
    (Boolean 1) == (Boolean 0) = False



class Booleanizable a where
    toBoolean :: (Booleanizable a) => a -> Boolean

instance Booleanizable Boolean where
    toBoolean (Boolean x) = Boolean x

instance Booleanizable Bool where
    toBoolean True = Boolean 1
    toBoolean False = Boolean 0
```

And what I'm trying to do:

```
instance (Num a) => Booleanizable a where
    toBoolean 0 = Boolean 0
    toBoolean _ = Boolean 1
```

This is the error that appears:

```
Boolean.hs:37:21:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘Booleanizable a’
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for ‘Booleanizable a’
```

Comment: Please show in the question what went wrong in your attempt. (In this case, I was able to correctly guess the error you got, but in other questions it might be trickier to do that.)

Comment: If the problem is simply the error `Constraint is no smaller than the instance head`, here is a good explanation and solution (use a newtype) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7198951/348716

Comment: updated the question. It's not that error. Sorry taking so long @duplode

Comment: No worries. If you turn on the `FlexibleInstances` extension as the error message suggests, you will get the "Constraint is no smaller [...]" error the other question discusses.

Answer (score 2):

I did three things to make your example working:

1.) At the beginning, I added two Language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

2.) I removed the self reference to `Booleanizable a` in the definition of the class Booleanizable:

Instead of

```
class Booleanizable a where
    toBoolean :: (Booleanizable a) => a -> Boolean
```

use

```
class Booleanizable a where
    toBoolean :: a -> Boolean
```

3.) I added an additional constraint `Eq a` to your last instance definition:

```
instance (Num a, Eq a) => Booleanizable a where
    toBoolean 0 = Boolean 0
    toBoolean _ = Boolean 1
```